# Magento Business Intelligence service errors

Tags: magento2, admin, cron

Every day we are seeing the following error appear at the top of the Magento admin interface:

[image]

The message states: `Failed to synchronize data to the Magento Business Intelligence service. [Retry Synchronization]`

If we click on the "Retry Synchronization" link the message goes away and does not return until the following day. Presumably the nightly cron process for the Business Intelligence service is having some issues.

The following errors are being logged in `var/log/debug.log` which relate to the analytics service:

```
[2020-09-09 11:00:04] main.ERROR: Cron Job analytics_subscribe has an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`oauth_token`, CONSTRAINT `OAUTH_TOKEN_CONSUMER_ID_OAUTH_CONSUMER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`consumer_id`) REFERENCES `oauth_consumer` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `oauth_token` (`consumer_id`, `type`, `token`, `secret`, `verifier`, `callback_url`, `user_type`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":63438848,"emalloc_start":60951528} [] []
```

We are running Magento 2.3.5-p1.

How can we troubleshoot this to identify the cause of the problem? We want to use the Magento Business Intelligence service (don't want to disable it).

Comment: Are you subscribed to the BI Service?

Comment: We don't have a subscription to the BI service but do want to use Advanced Reporting which should be free with M2. When I click on the "Go to Advanced Reporting" button on the dashboard it returns a 404. Advanced Reporting is enabled in the configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: Found some errors in debug.log - have added this to the question above.

Comment: Yes so if you disable the BI service subscription setting you should still be able to use advanced reporting as they are 2 separate services. so if you use the solution i posted before this should fix the error you are seeing in the admin

Comment: That error is also stating that you do not have a valid API key for the BI Service API

Comment: @DavaGordon Disabled the BI service and the errors have stopped occurring (thanks). Now just need to work out why the "Go to Advanced Reporting" link on dashboard returns a 404 when clicking on it but that's another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have an active subscription to Business Intelligence service id recommend running the following in the CLI

```
bin/magento config:set analytics/subscription/enabled 0
bin/magento cache:clean
```

This should stop that error from happening again